# Forge Autodesk Viewer window is truncated after resizing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have an app where we have a collapsible side panel and Forge Viewer window side by side. When we collapse the side panel the forge viewer windows seems to get resized, but actually the viewer doesn't get fully resized. The Navigation Cube and bottom toolbar appears okay though.[image]
Please check attached images. How should I get the viewer resized properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Viewer should resize with the parent element (e.g. DIV), but it may require you to trigger it with `viewer.resize()`

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I was setting the width on the canvas instead of the parent div. So we fixed that and additionally called `viewer.resize()` and problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Hi anyone who goes through this solution, sometimes viewer.resize() might not work, so write it in a setTimeOut function, and it definitely works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).